# Get the id of multiple html objects in an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

There are multiple objects in a div. I want to get the id of all those elements by their class. the number of elements can vary. I am doing it as

```
arr= $(".listitem #checkBox").hasClass('checkedItem').attr('id');
```

but it return only the first item

and if I use it as

```
arr= $(".listitem #checkBox").hasClass('checkedItem').map(function() {
     return this.id;
}).get();
```

The error on console is `Object true has no method 'map'`

How I can get the Ids of all  **CheckedItems**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`.hasClass()` method](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) returns a boolean indicating whether any elements in the jQuery object have that class, and a boolean doesn't have a `.map()` method.

Instead, make the class part of the selector, so that the jQuery object contains only elements with that class:

```
arr= $(".listitem #checkBox .checkedItem").map(function() {
     return this.id;
}).get();
```

Note that your original selector `".listitem #checkBox"` should only ever match one or zero elements, because id is supposed to be unique. For that reason I have assumed above that you are trying to check elements that are descendants of `#checkBox`. Let me know the structure of your html and I can tweak the selector to match...

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that you are trying to query for multiple items, but you are using an ID to look up.

```
arr= $(".listitem #checkBox")....
```

(the `#checkBox` part)

This code will never return an array.

[ID Attribute spec for HTML 4.01](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/struct/global.html#adef-id)

Answer (score 0):

Use this you will get all the id of checkeditems

```
var selected = new Array();
$('#checkbox input:checked').hasClass('checkedItem').each(function() {
    selected.push($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Comment: I wrote the same, but hasClass() returns a boolean so this is not working.